# Связи и каскадное удаление в SQLite-net

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, xamarin.android

Я практикуюсь в создании мобильных приложений на Xamarin с локальной базой данных SQLite. Я создал две простенькие сущности хотелось бы наладить между ними связь и каскадное удаление. Каскадное удаление по итогу не работает как и связь по всей видимости. Полагаю беда еще в том что в список сотрудников у профессии не сохраняются почему то объекты класса Person. Возможна ли вообще налаживание связей таким образом на SQLite-net?

Используется библиотека [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), не путать с Entity Framework.

Вот я описал две сущности проставил атрибуты для связи и каскадного удаления

```
public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement,NotNull]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Job))]
    public int Idjob { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeRead)]
    public Job Jobb { get; set; }

    public string job
    {
        get
        {
            string s = App.HRDB.GetJobAsync().Result.ToArray().Where(p => p.Id == Idjob).FirstOrDefault().Name;
            if (s == "")
                return "";
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот в этом методе я сохраняю нового сотрудника и записываю его в лист сотрудников в сущности job

```
private async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person person = (Person)BindingContext;
    if (person == null)
        person = new Person() { Fullname = Fullname.Text };
    Job job = jobs.Where(p => p.Name == CB.Items[CB.SelectedIndex]).FirstOrDefault();
    person.Idjob = job.Id;
    person.Jobb = job;
    if (job.people == null)
        job.people = new List<Person>();
    job.people.Add(person);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.Fullname) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.Idjob.ToString()))
    {
        await App.HRDB.SavePersonAsync(person);
        await App.HRDB.SaveJobAsync(job);
    }
    //Две точки что бы назад вернуться
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
}
```

Тут я сохраняю/обновляю сущность Job

```
public Task<int> SaveJobAsync(Job job)
{
    if (job.Id == 0)
        return db.InsertAsync(job);
    return db.UpdateAsync(job);
}
```

Далее при загружая профессию из бд, лист сотрудников в нем оказывается всегда null.

Comment: Разве не нужно вызывать метод `SaveChanges` (или `await db.SaveChangesAsync`) после всех изменений? Заметил ещё, что метод SaveJobAsync совершенно не асинхронный - не хватает `async-await`. Он синхронно вызывает асинхронные методы

Comment: Да и код в геттере свойства `job` можно вполне заменить на `return App.HRDB.GetJobAsync().Result.ToArray().Where(p => p.Id == Idjob).FirstOrDefault().Name;`. Всё остальное, что находится ниже - лишнее. И ещё, свойства именуются с большой буквы (`Job` нужно)

Comment: Так же, хотелось-бы спросить - такое большое количество логики обязательно должно находиться в методе `Save_Clicked`? Можно ли это вынести в какой-нибудь контроллер, из которого возвращать результат? Он должен был-бы проверять все входные данные и возвращать готовый результат

Comment: @Frehzy - это не EF, а другая ORM - SQLite-net. | С методом `SaveJobAsync` всё в порядке, такая запись допустима. `return` возвращает awaitable-объект.

Comment: Свойство `job` я бы заменил на метод, сделав его асинхронным. `GetJobAsync().Result` - не надо так делать. Обязательно нужно ожидать: `await ...GetJobAsync();`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, точно. Показалось на первый взгляд, что это EF. А так, да, я понимаю, что там возвращается такой ответ. Просто, как по мне, если вызываешь какие-то асинхронные методы - используй `await`. Варианты с использованием `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` или просто `.Result` тут явно не подойдут.